# jQuery mobile "stylesheet" for data- attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

There are plenty of examples in jQuery Mobile Demo page. But after seeing those it seems to me that we have come a great circle from HTML 4 to jQuery mobile. Let's see some samples.

```
<button type="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="expand">Expand last</button>
<button type="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="collapse">Collapse last</button>
...
```

It reminds me of old HTML 4 so much that it creeps me out.

```
<td align="right" bgcolor="green" colspan="5" rowspan="10" height="600" (...)>
```

Of course jQuery mobile has much wider capabilities and is much more compact. But this example makes me think that this framework is simply bad designed.

So I was searching some possibility to create something for jQuery Mobile which would be the same as CSS is for HTML.

```
<button type="button" data-icon="gear" data-custom="myComponent" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" data-icon="plus" data-custom="myComponent" id="expand">Expand last</button>
<button type="button" data-icon="minus" data-custom="myComponent" id="collapse">Collapse last</button>
...
```

and "jQuery mobile rule" (I will use CSS convention for this):

```
.myComponent {
    iconpos: right;
    mini: true;
    inline: true;
}
```

I know that data-attributes are "mapped" to classes. For example `data-iconpos="right"` to `class="ui-btn-icon-right"`.

So it would be possible to create some LESS or SASS scripts. However it's kind of hacking :/. So how this should be done best way to reuse set of data-attributes from jQuery mobile?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to reuse set of many data-attributes. In example above there are 3 attributes which are repeated over and over again.

Comment: `.myComponent {
    iconpos: right;
    mini: true;
    inline: true;
}` isn't a valid CSS btw.

Comment: I know that. That's why I'm looking for something which let me reuse set of data-attributes. I called it "jQuery mobile rule" and I pointed out that I will use CSS convention to show what I would like to get. I thought it would be clear. Sorry for misunderstanding.